# Calling security.authorization_checker service

Tags: symfony

Hi all and thansk for your time.

I'm working with `Symfony 3.0.2`and in a Class i'm trying to get the service security.authorization_checker in order to see the ROLE_ of who is connected to my application 
but i have this error :

Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType".
Did you mean to call e.g. "getBlockPrefix", "getName" or "getParent"?

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType  {



public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

    $roles = new LoadRoles();
   // $container = new Container();

  //  $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
    //LOAD ROLES FOR SUPER ADMIN
    if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')){
            $roles->getRolesForAdmin($builder, $options);
    }

    //LOAD ROLES FOR ADMIN
    if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
            $roles->getRolesForManager($builder, $options);
    }

    //LOAD ROLES FOR ASSOCIATION
    if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ASSOCIATION')){
        $roles->getRolesForAssociation($builder, $options);
    }

}
```

The probblem is located here : `$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')`
The function does not recognize the get() function since it does not extends Controller
I'm wondering if there is a way to access this service ? I'm new with Symfony please forgive my 
Sincerly

Comment: You are not trying to call it inside your *controller*, you're trying to call it inside your *FormType* - that's a difference. FormTypes generally don't have access to the service container. Perhaps it'd be better to edit the question and tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ccKep Thank you for your response i'll edit my post

Comment: Read up on defining your form type as a service and inject the authorization checker: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html#define-your-form-as-a-service You can also pass the authorization checker as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm($form, $item, array(
    'authService' => $this->get('security.authorization_checker')
));
```

In your form:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        //..
        ->setRequired('authService')
    ;
}
```

You can now access your service in the buildForm function:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $authService = $options['authService'];
    //...
}
```